# Asynchronous operation in router.use

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Expressjs and Mongoosejs. My routes look something like this:

```
router.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //check for matching API KEY in database for all routes that follow
  //Asynchronous Mongoosejs find.one
}

router.get('/status/:key/:token', function (req, res) {
  //more code here that needs to wait before being executed
}
```

Just wondering if the async function in the `router.use` will resolve before the `router.get` code is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it will as long as you use `next()` properly

Example:

```
router.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
  somethingAsync(function(err, result) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    // Do whatever
    return next();
  });
});
```

The router stack is called in the order routes are added to it. Calling `next()` calls the next route in the stack matching the provided path.

Calling `next(someError)`  calls the next error handling route in the stack.
Error handling routes have 4 arguments rather than 3.

Example error handling route:

```
router.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(500);
  return res.send('500: Internal Server Error');
});
```

Helpful Links:

- http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html
- http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html